# jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: index.html Render Error

Tags: python, flask, backend

when im trying to run the main.py i got TemplateNotFound: index.html

project file structure

> app
>
> > templates : base.html, index.html

> > static

> > views.py

````
## viwes.py 

from flask import render_template, request
from flask import redirect, url_for 



def base():
    return render_template('base.html')

def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

def faceapp():
    return render_template('faceapp.html')

##main.py 


from flask import Flask
from app import views

app = Flask(__name__)

#### URL
app.add_url_rule('/base', 'base',views.base)
app.add_url_rule('/','index', views.index)
app.add_url_rule('/faceapp','faceapp', views.faceapp)


### RUN 
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)```
````

Comment: Not clear from your diagram. Is the structure `./templates` or `./app/templates`? I wouldn't expect the latter to work.

Answer (score 0):

```
app = Flask(__name__, template_folder='path/to/templates/dir')
```

You can also explicitly define the path to the template directory as above.

**You can also refer [Flask Template](https://python-adv-web-apps.readthedocs.io/en/latest/flask3.html) for more details.**